# Why do jQuery's position() and offset() methods return fractional number in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have simple div tag, absolutely positioned within an HTML doc. 
When in Chrome I set its "right" CSS rule to a fixed value in pixels, and its "left" rule to "auto", and then immediately afterwards determine its left position using jquery's *position()* method, the value returned is something of this kind: **122.6363525390625**.
The same goes for the *offset()* method.

Firefox on the other hand, does not have this issue.

Can you tell me why this happens and if there's a way to prevent it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you setup a small example to demonstrate this behaviour? I could not reproduce it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wjvak/

Comment: Try the native method: `getComputedStyle( yourElem ).getPropertyValue( 'left' )`. If it returns a float number, then that's just what Chrome gives you and you'll have to convert the number to integer manually.

Comment: Note this can cause an issue with Telerik controls https://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/144661-fix-system-formatexception-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-thrown-o

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because when you use percentage widths that's what the math works out to. Imagine that you have this layout:

```
<div style="width: 111px">
    <div style="width: 50%"></div>
</div>
```

The inner element's width calculates to 55.5 pixels, not a natural number. Depending on the exact CSS attributes this could easily work out to quite a few more decimal places.

Chrome [uses subpixel rendering](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/LayoutUnit), so that's why you see this behavior.

Finally: I 'm not sure why this would cause you a problem, but of course if you want to round to a natural number you can use `Math.round(x)`.

Answer (score -3):

In Chrome the values are truncated, so 120, 120.5 and 120.6 all show the same width, so you don't need to worry about it using decimal value. There is nothing like .5 pixel. Pixel are whole units. If you do have this problem of functions returning decimal value then why not use parseInt? You shouldn't leave this thing to the browser to take care of or else your page may break.